# Dominated convergence theorem (bounded)

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, measurable-functions

I have a question concerning the dominated convergence theorem. For two sequences $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of random variables and a stopping time $\tau$ it is said that:

$\mathbb{E}[F_1(X_n)F_2(Y_n)\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau>n\}}]$=$\mathbb{E}[F_1(X_n)F_2(Y_n)\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau>n,|X_n|\geq n^{\varepsilon}\}}]+\sigma_n(1)$

for two bounded measurable functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ with the dominated convergence theorem for $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$.

Have someone a tip for me how the dominated convergence theorem is used there?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you really want $|X_n|\geq n^{\varepsilon}$ or should it be $|X_n|\leq n^{\varepsilon}$?

Comment: Yes i really want $|X_n|\geq n^{\epsilon}$. Thats how it is in my paper.

Comment: What is $\sigma_n(1)$ standing  for ?

Comment: I ask myself the same question.